# how to get workgroup name in vba?

Tags: vba, environment-variables

Is It possibly get this value?

[image]

Comment: I know get computer name but don't know how get workgroup name

Answer (score 2):

Unless your domain is more than one, you can retrieve by:

```
Environ("USERDNSDOMAIN") ' Or Environ("USERDOMAIN")
Environ("COMPUTERNAME")
```

It's same value as output of `set` in command prompt.